# How do I route groups of files in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, development, document-library

I need to build a solution in SharePoint 2016 where I can route an awards package.  An awards package is 3-5 individual files and the files all need to remain together at all times. My plan was to create a folder for each package with the person's name in my Document Library and we simply change a meta tag on the folder that would kick my email workflow. However, this does not appear possible. You cannot put the tag on the folder only on the individual files.

What is the most effective way to route a group of files together that is ultimatly user friendly? I can do low-level JSON if needed but would like to stick OOTB as much as possible.

Comment: Would you like to say a bit more about your goal? It seems you need to create a document set with a metadata column to add tags for it. And a workflow triggered by the change in that column and then send email to corresponding user. Anything more?

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was possible, simply forgot the right word. Document sets are the key to doing this which I am able to successfully deploy. I have used these before just forgot the correct words to search.